# Restore psn games from another account

Tags: psn

So I have 2 accounts on my playstation 3. I bought a game one the first one but accidentaly deleted it off of my system. ( By going to users and pressing triangle and deleted the account). Well I was wondering if I can retrieve those games from the first account and put them on the second. Yes, I have tried logging in to the first account but iy says my information ( email and password ) is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do account recovery on the first account, its the only way you can access the games.  Then log in, download the games you want, then switch to the second account (if thats where you'd prefer to play them).

If you accidentally bought the games recently on the first account, you could try contacting support to see if the'll refund so you can rebuy them on the second account.  Although its probably a long shot.

Comment: I think they're going to need to contact support anyways if he's getting that his e-mail/password are invalid.